# Working with https in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, asp.net, https

I have an asp.net MVC web application which is calling my Sharepoint Web application to fetch data from lists and libraries. Basically my MVC application is a web site for which data is being populated by calliing a Sharepoint api.

Now my problem is when Im using **http** protocol to connect to sharepoint application it workds fine.

But when I use **https** to connect to sharepoint application it does not work. What could be a possible solution for this scenario?

Suggestions are eagerly awaited.

Comment: Javascript or server side code? And have you verified the https site is 100% functional, with no certificate errors?

Comment: It is server side code. And yes my https site is 100% functional with no certificate erros.